# Visual Studio Setup Project (vdproj) - STDOLE, how to properly register COM DLL?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, vdproj

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Setup Project.

I have a COM DLL in setup that has a reference to the STDOLE (system type library, {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, that must not be registered, as of my understanding, because it is a protected file/registration). If you try to register it, you'll hit an error (warning) when installing the MSI.

Nevertheless, the vdproj extension adds the the registration for this DLL to the "TypeLib" MSI table. It appears that it does not do it always though, but under some conditions I cannot deduce. I have no option to exclude that tlb, it is somehow keeps reappearing (from dependencies probably?)

1. Why does vdproj tries to register that DLL that should not be registered?
2. How to avoid this? I tried adding manual post-edit of the produced MSI with a script to remove that tlb, and that worked; however it seems to be a completely wicked approach to the problem.

For this particular project, I am stuck with the Visual Studio Installer, and cannot switch to more reasonable and transparent alternatives (such as WiX). Any help or advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a VB6 COM dll? Is it a public DLL that you can put somewhere to look at? Maybe it is even a standard dll? Perhaps it is not even necessary to add?

Comment: It is a .NET assembly (that uses some things defined in the STDOLE). It's closed source, so I can't change this dependency :[

Comment: So it must be a .NET assembly that is registered for [COM interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973802(v=msdn.10)) then? It has been a while since I worked on that. Are there COM components in there as well (dlls, ocx, etc...)?

Comment: Correct, this is a .NET assembly to be registered for COM interop. Please note that this one is not "Primary Project Output" causing the issue, but a dependent assembly (that is auto-populated by the vdproj extension, under the "dependencies" list).

Comment: Updated my answer last night. The registry table approach will cause some validation issues, but it should work OK. I do believe registering the component prior to building should eliminate the registry key as well. Haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

***VB6 Runtime***: The registry key: **`Typelib\{000204EF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`** is part of the **`Visual Basic 6 Runtime`** and it is a known issue in WiX that **`heat.exe`** extraction of COM data erronously brings along this registry key for each ActiveX or COM component. **Note that this is not WiX's fault, but a general issue with VB6**. Hence the problem you see in Visual Studio installer projects as well.

> [**From the WiX help manual (for heat.exe)**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) (multi-purpose tool, one of which is COM registration extraction): "*...When registering a COM
>   component created in VB6 it adds registry entries that are part of the
>   VB6 runtime component. This flag is recommend for VB6 components to
>   avoid breaking the VB6 runtime on uninstall. The following values are
>   excluded: **`CLSID\{D5DE8D20-5BB8-11D1-A1E3-00A0C90F2731}`**, 
>   **`Typelib\{EA544A21-C82D-11D1-A3E4-00A0C90AEA82}`**, **`Typelib\{000204EF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`**, any interfaces that reference these two type libraries`*"

***Resolution***: And now the hard part, what is the actual fix? Frankly I don't have the time to test right now, but I suppose you can just open the final MSI with Orca and remove these entries - should they be there. I guess that is exactly what you are doing now, so you are back to square one, but at least there is a bit of clarity as to what causes the problem. *`I suppose you can try to run the build when the VB6 component is unregistered as opposed to when it is registered?`* That would make some sort of sense that it is only extracting the keys if the component is unregistered when you build? *`If this is the case, maybe try to self-register your VB6 component prior to the setup build`*.

---

***RegSpy.exe***: You can use a tool called [**RegSpy**](http://installsite.org/files/iswi/RegSpy2.zip) (or RegSpy2 actually) to extract the COM registration from a COM file. You can find the exe in the "Release" folder, then you go:

```
regspy.exe richtx32.ocx >> richtx32.reg
```

Then you can import the reg file to your Visual Studio Installer project. Remember to replace the hard coded paths with MSI directory properties and remove the erroneous VB6 entries mentioned above.

***VSProj***: In Visual Studio, **`Right click Visual Studio Installer Project`** => **`View`** => **`Registry`** => **`Right Click Top Node`** => **`Import...`**

Comment: Thank you for the info.. the thing is it is not WIX, but Visual Studio Setup Project (vdproj). With WIX one could simply do it all "by hand" and avoid auto-com-extraction. Also, it's not really a VB6 component, but a .NET assembly that has a reference to STDOLE.. For now yes, just removing these entries with "fix" script..

Comment: I guess you could just register the COM stuff via the registry table instead of the COM-tables if you have to. Provided the registration remains stable and isn't generated on every build of the dll you could then make do with the same registry data for every release. Let me have a look in Visual Studio.

Comment: Just to follow up. I have found no solution to the problem. This is just VDPOJ extension bug (it includes all dependencies in the typelib registration indiscriminately, i.e. regardless if it's a protected DLL that must not be either included or registered). Ended up rewriting the installer to WIX completely for that project.